# How to call the method by this(React Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
renderTopicList(){
    // console.log(this.props);
    //console.log(this.state.dataSource);
    return (
        <ListView
        style={Style.listView}
        ref="listview"
        pageSize={15}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
        renderRow={this.renderTopicListCell}
       // onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} 
        />
    );
}

renderTopicListCell(data){
    return (
        <TopicListCell
            onSelect = { () => this.selectTopic(data) }
            data={data} />
    );
}
selectTopic(data){

    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: '详细' + (data.replies_count ? '（' + data.replies_count.toString() + '条回复）' : ''),
        component: TopicView,
        passProps: {
            data: data
        }
    });
}
```

call onSelect in cell : `<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onSelect}/>`

when I hit the cell，it gives me the following error: _this3.selectTopic is not a function.(In '_this3.selectTopic(data)','_this3.selectTopic' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by two ways.

1) In your component constructor, You can bind the function you want to pass around. For e.g:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  // Binding the function 
  this.selectTopic.bind(this);
}
```

then, You can use pass it around with data

```
renderTopicListCell(data){
    return (
        <TopicListCell
            onSelect={this.selectTopic(data)}
            data={data} />
    );
}
```

2) You can bind the function when you're passing it.

```
<TopicListCell onSelect={this.selectTopic.bind(this, data)} data={data} />
```

I prefer former approach, that way I've all the bind calls at one place and I've to bind it once.

Comment: Thanks for help,and I want to know why can't use arrow founction here? The this in arrow founction references to class object?